# Фон с узором, плавно переходящий в цвет

Tags: css

Всем привет! Дайте совет, пожалуйста, или ткните носом =) Получил на верстку фон шапки такого вида:

[image]

тоесть узор плавно переходящий в сплошной цвет. Ситуация совершенно не патовая, прост хочется использовать самый оптимальный вариант. Если б градиента не было то нуль проблем - вырезал бы повторяющийся фрагмент узора и зарепитил по обеим осям. Тут надо другой подход. У меня пока 2 варианта:

1) Вырезать часть фона от верхней точки(с узором) до момента где начинается цвет (вышло изображение

[image]

4х360 пикс величиной 2,49 КБ), далее зарепитить по иксу, а остальное залить цветом.

2) Вырезать фрагмент узора

[image]

(4х4 пикс), залить им весь фон хедера. Потом в хвотошопе сделать фрагмент фона с вертикальным градиентом от прозрачного(сверху в низ) к цвету в который должен переходить фон хедера и наложить поверх фона с узором(зарепитить по иксу). PS: сорь за масло-маслянное, махните сто грамм для понимания)

Мож есть еще какой вариант более оптимальный? К кроссбраузерности не привязываться. Или я заморачиваюсь?

Comment: блок узора а на него сверху градиент по alpha чем не вариант ?

Answer (score 1):

```css
header {
  background: url('http://funkyimg.com/i/26E36.png');
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
header:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(125,185,232,0) 0%, rgba(30,87,153,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(125,185,232,0) 0%,rgba(30,87,153,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(125,185,232,0) 0%,rgba(30,87,153,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#007db9e8', endColorstr='#1e5799',GradientType=0 );
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Answer (score 0):

По простоте - первый.

По универсальности - второй.

В первом варианте вы ограничены высотой картинки и в случаи чего(ну мало ли блок надо будет увеличить по высоте) придется перерисовывать картинку под нужный размер.
Во втором варианте этой проблемы нет.